# How to make a server connection when app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-background

In my Android app I want to make a server connection, which should run when the app gets closed too.
The goal is to get notifications from the server and show them on the device

I tried to make a Service, in which I start the ServerConnection-Thread, but the thread stops when I close the app.

```
public class InternetService extends Service {
 public static final String START_SERVER = "startserver";
  public InternetService(){

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(START_SERVER)){
            //new thread to start server in non-ui-thread
            Thread server = new Thread(new Server());
            server.start();
        }


        return START_STICKY;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent server = new Intent(this, InternetService.class);
        server.setAction(InternetService.START_SERVER);
        startService(server);
    }
}


public class Server implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        server = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
        out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use something like a push method I would suggest you using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/). It's quite easy to use and is actually good for your purposes. If you need to pull a large amount of data I would suggest you to send a "poke" message with firebase and then download data with Volley (Http-API) or something similar. Cheers Tarik

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of services have changed with higher versions. Have a look https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

If you wish to send notification from server try using **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your service as a foreground service which would be persistent even when your app is closed. For that you only need to adda notification to your service. For android versions newer than android 8 it is required to create a notification channel to display the notification. You can read about it in the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java

Integrate the notification into your service file and start it as a foreground service. It can look like this then:

```
createNotificationChannel();
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channelID")
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
              .setContentTitle("My notification")
              .setContentText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
              .build();


 private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channelID",
                "Channel Name",
                importance
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
```